# Make changes to json string using jsonnet

Tags: json, kubernetes, prometheus, jsonnet

I want to change `namespace` in `alok-pod.json` in the below json using jsonnet.

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "items": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "v1",
            "data": {
                "alok-pod.json": "{\n  \"namespace\": \"alok\",\n  \"editable\": true,\n}"
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

Please suggest how this can be done using jsonnet?

Comment: Question has nothing to do with [kubernetes] or [prometheus].

Comment: Agree. But the audience of kubernetes and prometheus can help, as this is more of a common use case there

Comment: btw note `alok-pod.json` value is invalid json from its last `,`.

Comment: I've just published a little library intended to help with the cases like this: https://github.com/sbarzowski/jsonnet-modifiers.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE you'll need a `jsonnet` binary built from master, as `std.parseJson()` is not yet released as of 2019-02-26.

> **input.json**

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "items": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "v1",
            "data": {
                "alok-pod.json": "{\n  \"namespace\": \"alok\",\n  \"editable\": true\n}"
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

> **edit_ns.jsonnet**

```
// edit_ns.jsonnet for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54880959/make-changes-to-json-string-using-jsonnet
//
// NOTE: as of 2019-02-26 std.parseJson() is unreleased, 
// need to build jsonnet from master.

local input = import "input.json";

local edit_ns_json(json, ns) = (
  std.manifestJson(std.parseJson(json) { namespace: ns })
);

local edit_ns(x, ns) = (
  x {
    local d = super.data,
    data+: {
      [key]: edit_ns_json(d[key], ns) for key in std.objectFields(d)
    }
  }
);

[edit_ns(x, "foo") for x in input.items]
```

> Example run:

```
$ jsonnet-dev edit_ns.jsonnet
[
   {
      "apiVersion": "v1",
      "data": {
         "alok-pod.json": "{\n    \"editable\": true,\n    \"namespace\": \"foo\"\n}"
      }
   }
]
```